# Statement oriented approach against expression oriented one

Tags: java, read-eval-print-loop, jshell

I was going through this [article on java9](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3227244/java/java-9-is-here-everything-you-need-to-know.html?idg_eid=7a71ad7765f5ab064d7145e4d90a4292&email_SHA1_lc=6728b59fa46cc9b139ecc548c26a549066394c81&cid=ifw_nlt_infoworld_daily_2017-09-21&utm_source=Sailthru&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=InfoWorld%20Daily:%20Afternoon%20Edition%202017-09-21&utm_term=infoworld_daily&lipi=urn%3Ali%3Apage%3Ad_flagship3_messaging%3B%2F9QBQxIXTC2Tl48SSQusrQ%3D%3D) and came across this line where it states that ***Java is statement-oriented whereas REPLs are expression-oriented.***

Can somebody explain the difference between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick and coincidently visible difference is that following types of expressions can be made into a statement by terminating the expression with a semicolon (`;`).

- Assignment expressions
- Any use of ++ or --
- Method invocations
- Object creation expressions
- Such statements are called expression statements.

So when in your `HelloWorld.java` class the following would not compile -

```
int z = 1 //(; missing)
```

[Jshell](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/222) on its prompt successfully stores the value as:

```
jshell> int z = 1
z ==> 1
```

---

Morevoer

> [Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)
>   are roughly equivalent to sentences in natural languages. A statement
>   forms a complete unit of *execution*.

whereas an `Expression` is a construct made up of variables, operators, and method invocations, which are constructed according to the syntax of the language, that evaluates to a single value.